# fprintf on formatted string

Tags: c

I'm trying to get the following to display

```
static const char MSG[] = "Test %ld\n";
static int COUNT = 5;

fprintf(stdout, "%s", MSG, COUNT);
```

but at the moment, the outputs display

```
Test %ld
```

How can I format the `%ld` to display 5 instead?

Comment: Change to `fprintf(stdout, MSG, COUNT);`

Comment: @sashoalm Make it an answer.

Comment: @MarounMaroun No, because the question should be closed as "typographical error", not answered.

Comment: @sashoalm I disagree, this is not a typographical error. OP simply misused the function. Although I voted to close for this reason, but I cannot remove my vote.

Comment: @RobertLu Please do us a favor and **think about what was wrong and why the propsed fix works.**

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void )
{
  static const char MSG[] = "Test %ld\n";
  static int COUNT = 5;

  fprintf(stdout, MSG, COUNT);

  return ( 0 );
}
```